# sql query in teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I am working on a query that will result in returning Names of top ten people from table with highest length.
The query is as :

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) As frequency
FROM    loadbise.student
GROUP   BY name
ORDER   BY COUNT(*) DESC
Where   name is Not Null
sample 10;
```

It returns me top ten from bottom. I want to select top ten from most highest value to 2nd most highest value and so on.
Top function is not working on teradata 6 (my version).

Comment: Yup works fine. No error

Comment: After `ORDER BY` you should be using `HAVING` clause, not `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 name, COUNT(*) As frequency
FROM    loadbise.student
WHERE   name is Not Null
GROUP   BY name
ORDER   BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

You can review the documentation [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_111A/ch01.032.090.html).  `TOP` and `SAMPLE` do not do the same thing.

Comment: It gives error of "Insert something between top and 10"